# KendoUI Scheduler server filtering with correct dates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

#### The problem

I'm trying to use the KendoUI Scheduler widget (MVC helpers) to filter appointments in a particular time zone (say, 'Europe/Minsk'), on a computer set to my own time zone, in Tasmania. The Scheduler widget's time zone is set to 'Europe/Minsk'. I've enabled server filtering according to Telerik's code library example (http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendoui-scheduler-server-filtering). However, the server call for the week view is providing the wrong dates and times to the server, providing a UTC date string equivalent to midnight on Monday in my own time zone, instead of the configured time zone.

It's easy enough to see why; it appears that the `scheduler.view().startDate()` in my `getAdditionalData()` function returns something like: `Date {Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (Tasmania Standard Time)}`, which is converted to "2015-10-18T13:00:00.000Z", rather than the local equivalent *relative to the configured time zone*. In short, the call to `scheduler.view().startDate()` is returning the wrong date given the configured time zone.

#### The question

How can I get around this apparent issue? I don't see any other way of knowing the date range the scheduler is displaying, and it seems the only way to retrieve it is broken.

The issue is reproducible with the unchanged code library example. Just try dragging an appointment the the last hours of the week, and watch it disappear altogether after refreshing.

For quick reference, the getAdditionalData function is as follows:

```
function getAdditionalData() {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").getKendoScheduler();

    var result = {
        start: scheduler.view().startDate().toISOString(),
        end: scheduler.view().endDate().toISOString()
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vladimir's answer provided a way to convert the date range to UTC, however the date range displayed on the scheduler is not in UTC, but the configured time zone.

Using the fabulous moment.js, I was able to convert it to the correct date range:

```
function getFilters() {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").getKendoScheduler();
    var start = moment.tz(getDateParts(scheduler.view().startDate()), scheduler.options.timezone);

    // Assuming the scheduler will never show part days, the end date needs an extra day to ensure events on the day are included.
    var actualEnd = new Date(scheduler.view().endDate());
    actualEnd.setDate(actualEnd.getDate() + 1);

    var end = moment.tz(getDateParts(actualEnd), scheduler.options.timezone);

    var result = {
        start: start.toISOString(),
        end: end.toISOString()
    }

    return result;
}

function getDateParts(date) {
    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        date.getMonth(),
        date.getDate(),
        date.getHours(),
        date.getMinutes(),
        date.getSeconds()
    ];
}
```

This now queries the web service for all events falling within the visible date range, which it does correctly. <strike>Now I just need to figure out why the Scheduler widget is not displaying any events on the last day of the week view, despite these being returned in the web service call with the correct UTC times.</strike>

**Edit**: The reason that events on the last day weren't rendering was because I unintentionally changed the endDate of the view(). Of course; dates are not immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: From the provided information it seems that the dates are still not handled on the server side correctly. Using the settings from my reply below events in the exact end time of the view are returned. Also you can apply timezones to the dates using the methods available in "kendo.timezone" namespace, instead of using third party library.

Comment: By the way if my last suggestion works as expected on your side as well, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct.

Comment: @Vladimir-Iliev I already tried upvoting your answer as helpful, however my rep points are too low to make a difference. Doesn't help when somebody has down-voted my question *and* my answer.

Answer (score -2):

First I would suggest to check the new (and extremely helpful) "Timezones" help article which explains the Timezones, JavaScript Date object, how the Scheduler works with them and how the remote service should handle the dates:

- [Scheduler: Timezones](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/timezones)

**Final edit:** Here is the solution after the last clarifications here and inside related support thread:

*After some additional testing on our side and reading you last response I finally get what exactly is the issue that you are experiencing. The solution includes the previously suggested handling of the dates on the server side (due to the MVC DefaultModelBinder behavior) and some changes of the client-side code. Please check it below - it will be applied to the previously linked demo in GitHub (after some additional testing on our side) and StackOverflow:*

1. *Client side code for getting the correct range start/end dates (including startTime/endTime of the view):*

   ```
   function getAdditionalData() {
       var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

       var timezone = scheduler.options.timezone;
       var startDate = kendo.timezone.convert(scheduler.view().startDate(), timezone, "Etc/UTC");
       var endDate = kendo.timezone.convert(scheduler.view().endDate(), timezone, "Etc/UTC");

       //optionally add startTime / endTime of the view
       var startTime = kendo.date.getMilliseconds(scheduler.view().startTime());
       var endTime = kendo.date.getMilliseconds(scheduler.view().endTime());
       endTime = endTime == 0 ? kendo.date.MS_PER_DAY : endTime;

       var result = {
           Start: new Date(startDate.getTime() - (startDate.getTimezoneOffset() * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE) + startTime),
           End: new Date(endDate.getTime() - (endDate.getTimezoneOffset() * kendo.date.MS_PER_MINUTE) + endTime)
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```
2. *Class for converting the dates to UTC on the server side:*

   ```
   public class FilterRange
   {
       private DateTime start;
       public DateTime Start
       {
           get
           {
               return start;
           }
           set
           {
               start = value.ToUniversalTime();
           }
       }

       private DateTime end;
       public DateTime End
       {
           get
           {
               return end;
           }
           set
           {
               end = value.ToUniversalTime();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. *Controller on the server side:*

   ```
   public virtual JsonResult Read(FilterRange range)
   {
       return Json(taskService.GetRange(range.Start, range.End));
   }
   ```

**[Here is a screencast](http://screencast.com/t/pBZ9h0cgBXJe)** of the above solution tested in two different timezones.

Comment: The string passed to the server is in UTC (note the Z suffix), and it is interpreted correctly. The problem is that the date is wrong to begin with. It's starting midnight Monday in Tasmania Standard Time, instead of the Tasmanian equivalent of midnight Monday in Europe/Minsk, which I believe, should be `Date {Mon Oct 18 2015 16:00:00 GMT+1100 (Tasmania Standard Time)}`.

Comment: Sorry, make that `Date {Mon Oct 19 2015 08:00:00 GMT+1100 (Tasmania Standard Time)}`

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir-Iliev, the scheduler.view().startTime() function looks like it solves the issue of getting the correct time of day to query. It's probably important to note that it doesn't exist for the month view.